# How to keep an object in a fixed position while scrolling?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like to have my social profile buttons scroll just like its done on 9gag. Their 2 ads on the right hand side stay in a fixed position once you scroll to a certain point. I would like to do the same. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks alot guys.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `position: fixed` to the element once the scroll offset reached a certain point.

Comment: i appreciate the response. However, i have no clue how this is done. Can you help with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Define this CSS then add id="media_icons" to the element you want fixed. Change the style according to your needs.

```
#media_icons {
clear: both;
height: 34px;
margin-right: 33px;
margin-top: 32px;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 148px;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work. Here is the URL http://humorousfunnyjokes.com/ The previous, next and random buttons at the bottom of the sidebar is what i need to scroll. Thanks again